# Plotting a data file using matrix with image and multiple arrows

Tags: gnuplot

How can I plot a data file matrix with image and some horizontal lines (no head arrows) on the same figure? I already tried this code:

```
set arrow 2 nohead from 0,50, graph 0 to 200,50, graph 1 front lc "black"
set arrow 2 nohead from 0,200, graph 1 to 200,200, graph 2 front lc "black"
plot 'data.txt' matrix w image
```

but only displays one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number after `set arrow` identifies an arrow for later changes and must be unique. You overwrite the first arrow with the second one by using the same tag number. You can simply omit it:

```
set arrow nohead from 0,50 to 200,50 front lc "black"

set arrow nohead from 0,200 to 200,200 front lc "black"

plot 'data.txt' matrix w image
```

Your coordinate definitions were also wrong. You must specify only two values,not three for `plot`. And the `graph` coordinate system is usually meaningful only for the range 0..1